# Angular Material md-select Displaying quantity selected

Tags: angular-material

Is there a way using Md-select for angular material to display how many checkboxes were checked instead of displaying all of the selected values. For example If I have 4 options pepperoni, cheese, sausage and veggies and I select three of them . How would I display "3 Selected", Instead of writing out the entire selections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/dOpbpE?editors=1010#0)

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="SelectOptGroupController as vm" class="md-padding" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div>
    <h1 class="md-title">Pick your pizza toppings</h1>
    <md-input-container md-no-float>
      <label>Toppings</label>
      <md-select ng-model="vm.selectedToppings" multiple="" md-selected-text="vm.text" md-offset="0 30">
        <md-option ng-value="topping.name" ng-repeat="topping in vm.toppings">{{topping.name}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('SelectOptGroupController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.toppings = [
      { name: 'Pepperoni' },
      { name: 'Cheese' },
      { name: 'Sausage' },
      { name: 'Veggies' }
    ];
    vm.selectedToppings = [];
    $scope.$watch("vm.selectedToppings", function () {
      vm.text = vm.selectedToppings.length + " Toppings selected";
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes!!! like once your done display you selected three toppings in the place-holder section. I see in your example it still lists out all the orders picked in the input. Thanks I will try that out

Comment: @Flash See updated CodePen and answer to hide selection in the input.

Comment: Thannks, so is not possible to have it where the topping is displayed?

Comment: @Flash Check the updated CodePen. I won't update the answer until I get what you want :-)

Comment: @Flash Check the CodePen.

Comment: Thanks That was exactly what I'm looking for. Im actually not using $scope. my controler is set up like this. var vm=this; and my variables are set utp like vm.test = onclick; vm. querySearch = querySearch. Vm.list =[]. etc. Woudl it still work if I'm now using $scope

Comment: @Flash See updated answer and CodePen. You still need $scope for the $watch. If this answers your question please mark it as so for future readers.

Comment: I sure Will thanks a lot for the help and your patience

Comment: I realized it's not working for me because I'm using the early version of angular material