# AngularJS $watch does not work with bind object

Tags: angularjs

I would like to implement the same behaviour like here 
[Angular Material md-select Displaying quantity selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614619/angular-material-md-select-displaying-quantity-selected)
 (counting selected items in a multiple select )
But it does not work, here is my code and fiddle :

```
<div ng-app="selectDemoOptGroups" ng-controller="SelectOptGroupController" >
    <md-select md-selected-text="selectedText" ng-model="selectedToppings"  multiple>   
        <md-option ng-value="topping.name" ng-repeat="topping in toppings">{{topping.name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>


.module('selectDemoOptGroups', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('SelectOptGroupController', function($scope) {

  $scope.toppings = [
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Pepperoni' },
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Sausage' },
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Ground Beef' },
    { category: 'meat', name: 'Bacon' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Mushrooms' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Onion' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Green Pepper' },
    { category: 'veg', name: 'Green Olives' }
  ];
  $scope.selectedToppings = [];       

  $scope.$watch("$scope.selectedToppings.length", function() {
      if ($scope.selectedToppings.length > 0){
            $scope.selectedText = $scope.selectedModel.length + " selected";
      }
      else {
            $scope.selectedText = "Toppings";
      }
  },true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexLavriv/ya6eu8kz/2/
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use exactly the same **`$scope`** variable for watch, it should be just **`selectedToppings`**

also it should be

```
 $scope.selectedText = $scope.selectedToppings + " selected";
```

instead of

```
$scope.selectedModel.length + " selected";
```

**CODE**

```
  $scope.$watch("selectedToppings", function() {
       if ($scope.selectedToppings.length > 0){
          $scope.selectedText = $scope.selectedToppings + " selected";
        }
       else{
          $scope.selectedText = "Toppings";
       }
    },true);
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ya6eu8kz/3/)**

Comment: did you check the demo?

Comment: you need to change this line as well   $scope.selectedText = $scope.selectedModel.length + " selected"; as mentioned above